# Android 11 Storage Access Framework - How to use files?

Tags: storage-access-framework, android-11, storage-access-api

Hey there fellow devs,

I have come across a problem while migrating our app to the new API 30 standards with the storage access framework (SAF).

I have successfully migrated the file structure and am now using the internal (FilesDir) paths.

Getting images with the MediaStore-Api is also working quite nicely.

But there is one big issue I just can't seem to fix.

In our app, we are using the API "Mapsforge" for Offline-Maps.

This API is using a Java.IO.File-Object we get from a path to a ".map" file which is almost 2GB large.

This file does not come from us, it is a file managed by the customer and put onto the device for us to use, since all the ".Map"-Files are custom.

Since the SAF is returning an Android.Net.Uri, I can't seem to convert it to a Java.IO.File without copying the contents of the file and therefore using even more storage on the device.

Is there any way to use the SAF to get a Java.IO.File-Object I can use in code?

If not, then Android 11 is making it very hard for my Customer to manage his storage.

Answer (score 0):

> This API is using a Java.IO.File-Object we get from a path to a ".map" file which is almost 2GB large.

With luck, Mapsforge will offer more flexible APIs in the future. You may wish to contact them about their recommendations.

> Is there any way to use the SAF to get a Java.IO.File-Object I can use in code?

No. After all, the user might choose something on Google Drive or another cloud storage provider, rather than a local file. Or, they might choose a file that is inaccessible to your app. Or, they might choose content that is stored in an encrypted file, which needs to be decrypted by the document provider. And so on.